# how extend webkit in C/C++

Tags: webkit, webkit-transform

I would like to learn how to extend JavaScript functionality by adding some plug-ins to webkit based browsers.

Any link or tutorial from where I can start.

I looked into  http://rvr.typepad.com/wind/2011/10/webkit-extending-javascript-1.html

but it used GTK+, I am looking webkit enhancement in C/C++

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have some confusion...

Why did you tag this "firefox-addon" and "firefox-addon-sdk" when Firefox is not Webkit based?  (It uses [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29)).

Also, GTK+ [is a C++ wrapper over the C interface to a GUI toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B).  (?)

If you want some good opportunities to mess with WebKit, you can [install Qt Creator](http://qt.digia.com/product/developer-tools/) and try out their WebKit examples, which include plugins as well as some more basic integration:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-webkit.html

You should read up on NPAPI/PPAPI if your goal is to write plugins for existing web browsers:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI